# Unable to render inner HTML for AJAX form with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I've coded a straightforward form which submits via Mailchimp's API to a waiting list.

This works, and the form upon submission doesn't reload the page (good), and submits the request to the server to store in Mailchimp (also good).

However, I'm wanting to update the inner HTML of the form to reflect whether the form was submitted successfully or not, without reloading the page. I've followed other questions but can't get it to work.

Here's my code at present:

Form -

```
<form id="early-access" class="hero-form " action="early-access" method="POST">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
            <button class="cta-button" type="submit" name="button">Get early access</button>
          </form>
```

My AJAX jQuery code -

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $("#early-access").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(),
           done: function(data)
           {
               alert(data);
           }
         });
});

  </script>
```

**EDIT: Now adding my Early Access POST code. Noting that the form successfully adds the user to my waiting list..**

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;

  const data = {
    members: [{
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed"
    }]
  };

  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

  const url = process.env.MAILCHIMPURL;

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    auth: process.env.MAILCHIMPAPIKEY
  };

  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {

    response.on("data", function(data) {
      // console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();

};
```

Also for reference - my backend is Node.js, not PHP.. Not sure if that impacts things with jQuery either.

The 'alert' in the success / error call in my AJAX isn't working, neither is my console.log. There's no mention of the request in my log. If the alert was working, I'd assume that I could just use .html to update the #early-access form.. I've tried that already but no luck unfortunately.

**EDIT: In my console, after perhaps 2 minutes (roughly) after successfully submitting my form I get a 'error' alert pop up, and my console shows a 'Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost' error.**

If anyone could advise, that'd be appreciated!

Comment: Can you see ajax being called at all in your browser network console ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, but in my Browser Console, there's no mention of anything relating to the form. The AJAX request is clearly working in some capacity as it's submitting the form and not reloading the page, but there's no response from it. :-/ Hope that helps? EDIT: Just noticed that after a period of time, I get an alert saying 'An error occurred' even when it successfully submits..

Comment: I think posting the code from your node server would help

Comment: I've just added it :-) Thank you